# doxygen confused between a member method and a local variable which have the same name？

Tags: doxygen

I am now reading the source code of QuickFix engine thus I wanna gen a called-by graph using doxygen. As It finished I found it didn't determine function call relationship correctly for it wrongly detected a reference to a local veriable as a member function which have a same name.

here is the output of doxygen, the symbol **start** is wrongly detected as the member of it superclass
[image: doxygen output]

I'm using doxygen 1.9.4 and graphviz on windows. Have use doxygen to generate called-by graph on other project before with same setting and it worked well.

Comment: Please add a complete code example that makes it possible to reproduce the problem (for the settings use `doxygen -x Doxyfile` so you only get the differences compared to the default settings).